# How do I ask for a higher compensation when the work I'm doing is meant for higher ranks?

Tags: professionalism, promotion

In the company I'm currently employed, there's a 5-degree career plan, with very distinct functions.

Step 2 (Programmer) is supposed to do the programming per se. Analysts and higher (Steps 3, 4 and 5) define what must be done, programmers decide how (technically) and execute it.

I'm no longer doing any development. I'm currently meeting with clients, documenting things and forwarding the development to a team of programmers. This is not something I decided to do, those are the orders I got from management. I also have to do lots of reports, including team reviews.

Here's the catch: the company does not allow a promotion to analyst without a bachelors degree, which I don't have (yet! I'm working on it, but will take at least another 1.5 years to complete). I feel this is a little too convenient - I can do the work, but can't get paid accordingly.

I'm going through some financial distress and I'd like to ask them to make an exception for my case. What they are doing is actually illegal where I live. I don't want to threaten with a lawsuit (obviously - I don't have any intention of doing anything about it), nor do I want to sound like I'll stop doing what I'm being told to do if I don't get promoted (even though this is what I'd like to do).

How should I proceed without sounding like I'm entitled or just plain lazy and without risking losing my job?

Comment: Do you want to be sure you are still employed there after you get your degree?

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Comment: If they followed the law, would the result be that you were paid more, or did a lower level of work?

Comment: @joe, in Brazil there are two things called "attribute deviation" and "wage parity". The first one happens when an employer hires someone to do a subpaid work, but in reality ends up making him do what was supposed to be a higher paid job. The second one demands all employees with the same attributions get paid the same (regardless of titles, as long as they were hired within a 2-year time frame). Wife's a lawyer.

Comment: @thursdaygeek either one would be fine.

Comment: @joe, there are also other analysts (one was hired on the same day I was!) doing exactly the same thing I am (in the same project). We discuss everything before delegating tasks to the other programmers. This falls right into the "wage parity" thing.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro - I am not familiar with Brazilian law, but since they stipulate a degree for your level of work, your legal grounds may not be as strong as you believe.

Comment: @ComeAndGo, you'd be right if my profession was regulamented (like doctors, engineers, etc). Since it's not, the law says if I can't have the job (because I don't have a degree), I can't *do* the job either. If I'm already *doing* the job, I should be paid accordingly.

Comment: @Pedro:Very nice, pay everyone the same. That is really motivating for those who would otherwise be very ambitious and excel at their job. Since that doesn't matter, people will do "just enough" to keep their job since it isn't going to help their pay for them to put in the extra effort.

Comment: @Dunk Dude, I'm just reading it, I didn't make the rule. And if you think about it, it kinda makes sense. If you have two employees with different skill levels, they should **not** be doing the same things. You can also have productivity bonuses, but the base salary must be the same.

Comment: At larger companies, most of the time, the employee proves they are ready for promotion by already successfully performing the duties of the higher level position before they are actually promoted. So your situation doesn't seem out of the ordinary if it doesn't go on for more than a couple of years. However, a degree matters. Some contract bid proposals require this information as they use it as a gauge for whether the contractor can really do the job or not. Also, some government contracts have separate billing rates for degreed versus non-degreed contractor employees.

Comment: @Pedro:I didn't say you made the rule, I didn't know that rule existed anywhere and had to comment on the obvious downside. Anyways, the rule doesn't make sense unless you assume that people with the same credentials and background will perform at about the same level. That is absolutely not true. Now to the extent that productivity bonuses come into play, that could wipe out my entire concern as then workers would have reasons to excel and be motivated. Of course those bonuses better be really big to have any effect at all.

Comment: @Dunk, your concerns are perfectly valid. But reality is that Brazil is a f@#ed up place, and if you don't regulate things, employers will end up hiring everyone as janitors and making them develop software, just because it's cheaper. It's the worst I'm-smarter-than-the-system culture in the world.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps explain that you are experiencing financial hardship, and since you are doing the work of an analyst and working on the degree, maybe they can make an exception and pay you as an analyst for a **stipulated period of time** - for example until you can negotiate your financial difficulties (six months or a years, etc) or a reasonable amount of time for you to finish your degree and acquire the official `Analyst` title, so you can be duly compensated without a special exception.

Do not ask for a "blanket exception", one that relinquishes you from all responsibility - IMO that doesn't smell right.

Also make sure that you are indeed doing the work that demands higher pay, and that you aren't dealing with a perception problem: Doing more than you think you are. You can probably verify this by talking to co-workers, etc.